# Sub-city-level data on criminal behavior – without relying on crime reports?

Tags: usa, crime, chicago

I am attempting to measure what proportion of crimes committed lead to arrests in Chicago, and whether that rate varies in different parts of the city.

I'd like to do this with without relying on crime report data because the definition of "criminal" behavior varies, as does the likelihood of residents to report it.

The types of "criminal" behaviors I am interested in are: drug use/sales; theft, burglary and/or robbery; battery/assault; vandalism; and (illegal) firearm possession/use.

Any ideas for datasets that could provide a fuller picture than crime reports of the frequency of these behaviors on a sub-city level, or maybe on a demographic level?